# how to remove duplicates (with original value) from a vector in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I wrote the program to remove the duplicates from a given set of numbers. but i am not getting required output.Instead i am getting SIGSTP runtime error each time. input/output format is something like this:
      input: 1 2 5 7 1 4 2
      output: 5 7 4
my code is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        vector<int> v_num;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int x;
            cin >> x;
            v_num.push_back(x);
       }
       vector<int>::iterator it;
       for(it=v_num.begin();it!=v_num.end();)
       {
           int val=*it;
           int flag=0;
           vector<int>:: iterator j;
           for(j=it+1;j!=v_num.end();)
           {
               if(val==*j)
               {
                   v_num.erase(j);
                   flag=1;
               }
               if(flag==0)
                  j++;
           }
           if(flag==1)
                { v_num.erase(it);
                 flag=1;}
           if(flag==0)
                 it++;
       }

        for(int i=0;i<v_num.size();i++)
           { cout <<v_num[i]<<endl;
            }
    }

}
```

it is my first question on online platform,so sometimes I may not be clear. In that case any suggestion or further clarification needed can be posted in comment section. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem of your Code is that you erase Elements and use the iterators later on.

e.g.

```
       for(j=it+1;j!=v_num.end();)
       {
           if(val==*j)
           {
               v_num.erase(j);
```

I just copy-and-pasted it from your Code. You erase `j` and on the next Iteration you use `it` again which most probably is invalid

Erasing from a vector invalidates the iterators.

This is one of the cases where you should use an `std::list` instead of an `std::vector`

Comment: If I save the "it" before changing it and after changing if I will use the saved value then should it work??

Comment: I mean, whenever i change the value of iterator i can save its value before changing it and later on I use the saved value.

Comment: No you can not save in iterator, it will be invalidated too. The only way you can save in iterator is to save its index and "restore" it like `v_num.begin() + index`

Answer (score 1):

You really should not be using vectors like that. Erasing from the middle of the vector causes it to reallocate all the following values every time. At that point all iterators become invalid, which probably causes your runtime error.

In short, when you call `erase` on the vector, both iterators `it` and `j` become invalid, and should not be used.

You can either use `std::unique` or simply use `std::set` to store the unique values to begin with, avoiding the vector all together, since you're reading the values just a few lines above.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this

```
vector<int> vec{1,1,2,3,4,4,2,5,6};
sort(begin(vec), end(vec));
auto last = unique(begin(vec), end(vec));
vec.erase(last, end(vec));
```

to make std::unique work the range should be sorted beforehand 
 
EDIT:
I see I haven't done what the question required because I was looking at other answer. I managed to write a function to return a vector with unique numbers but it allocates temporary counting array and eventually copies elements from vector that were unique. Any comments on this appreciated.

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> erase_duplicated(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    const size_t n = vec.size();
    int* duplicates = new int[n];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) duplicates[i] = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
            if(vec[i] == vec[j])
            {
               ++duplicates[i];
               ++duplicates[j];
            }
    }
    std::vector<T> temp;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if(!duplicates[i])
            temp.push_back(vec[i]);
    }
    delete [] duplicates;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: oh, and it can be optimised by skipping iterations of elements where the counter is already greater than zero